# How can I read specific data from text file using C# or Vue.js?

Tags: c#, vuejs3

I want to read specific data from the text file shown below :

[image].

How can I do this using C# or Vue.js?

Comment: did you tried ? any attempts ..

Comment: Read the file line by line until you reach totals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, you can read all the lines using File.ReadAllLines() (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1).

Loop through the lines (or use a Linq Where() statement) until you find the one with "total."